# Having trouble with ArrayList to ListView

Tags: android, listview, arraylist

I am having trouble with setting my list view from my arraylist, the error is "cannot resolve symbol discussions_list". discussions_list is the id of the listView within my discussions_layout.xml file and this is how I have called it "android.R.layout.discussions_list" I'm sure the error is in there, but I am unaware of how to fix it.

Code: Discussions_Fragment.java

```
    private ArrayAdapter populateListView(ArrayList titles)
{
    //Create list of items

    //Build adapter
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.discussions_list,titles);

    //Configure the list view

    return arrayAdapter;
}
```

Code: discussiont_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#ff00b8ff">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Discussions"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/discussions_list"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

Answer (score 3):

**Mistake:**

1) You are trying to access in-built resources. FYI, android.R contains all the in-built resources.

```
android.R.layout.discussions_list
```

2) You can't access the views by passing the layout in `ArrayAdapter` but you have to find views first and then access the particular view.

**Correct:**

1) Access the resources in R file of your project using:

```
R.layout.discussions_list
```

2) You just need to pass `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` in `ArrayAdapter`, instead of passing your layout as an argument, this simple_list_item_1 would act as a row layout file for each list items.

Comment: I originally had R.layout.discussions_list but it was throwing the same error that I get with android.R.layout.discussions_list, The "discussions_list" part is underlined and in red so I believe that part is the error.

Tried again without android. and it has the same error 

    Error:(100, 84) error: cannot find symbol variable discussions_list

Comment: @MatthewWren Do you know how to find the views by ID and access them in Java?

Comment: no i don't, this is my first attempt at making an app

and i changed that and got a different error Error:(100, 45) error: no suitable constructor found for ArrayAdapter(Discussion_Fragment,int,ArrayList)
constructor ArrayAdapter.ArrayAdapter(Context,int,int) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; Discussion_Fragment cannot be converted to Context)
constructor ArrayAdapter.ArrayAdapter(Context,int,String[]) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; Discussion_Fragment cannot be converted to Context)
constructor ArrayAdapter.ArrayAdapter(Context,int,List<String>) is not applicable

Comment: @MatthewWren one of the best resource to start with android application development https://www.udacity.com/course/developing-android-apps--ud853